# Why mutt fails to send an email with some tgz file attachment?

Tags: debian, email, tar, mutt

I use Debian7 and mutt (ver 1.5.21) and use command line to send emails with attachments. Normally, I have no problem in sending emails with attachment, but I have one problem in sending an email with a particular tgz file from tar(using -c -z -v -f options). It is sending to a gmail recipient.

It is about 4MB, and there is no error logged in log file. It is shown as sent in the 'sent' file. I can send files larger than 10MB, so attachment size does not seem to be the cause. I also can send some other tgz files in sizes of 2MB without any problem.

Where can I look to find the cause of this problem?  Thank you very  much.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I just found out that there are js(javascript) files in the directory, and gmail blocks emais with file types like js.  After I exclude the dir that has the js files, the email comes as expected.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail blocks emails with attachment that includes the file type like js, vb, jar, and etc.